# weird bug on radio buttons when change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to do a radio button with 2 options: yes and no (is a long form), but in this piece, i need that radio called refused or accomplished be checked when the user choose yes or no, refused and accomplished buttons already are disabled, the user can't change this manually.

1 - when user choose yes: accomplished must be checked
2 - if user choose no, refused must be checked.
3 - if user change the yes to no, or no to yes option we back to the rules 1 or 2 above.

however, i'm stuck because when i change the option the radio button change only once. and nothing happens after that.

this is my code right now: https://jsfiddle.net/bw21cxo5/1/

HTML:

```
<div>
  <label for="yes">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="yes" id="yes" class="option-yes">Yes
  </label>
  <label for="no">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="no" id="no" class="option-no">No
  </label>
</div>
<br><br>
<div>
  <label for="refused">
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="refused" disabled> Refused
  </label>
  <label for="accomplished">
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="accomplished" disabled> Accomplished
  </label>
</div>
```

js: (jquery 2.2)

```
$('input[name="radio1"]').on('change', function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass('option-no')) {
    $('#refused').attr('checked', true);
    $('#accomplished').attr('checked', false);
  } else {
    $('#accomplished').attr('checked', true);
    $('#refused').attr('checked', false);
  }
});
```

Comment: Use `prop` instead of `attr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works enough, only a little fix:

```js
$(function () {
  $('input[name="radio1"]').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('option-no')) {
      $('#refused').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('#accomplished').prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>


<div>
    <label for="yes">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="yes" id="yes" class="option-yes">Yes
    </label>
    <label for="no">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="no" id="no" class="option-no">No
    </label>
</div>
<br><br>
<div>
    <label for="refused">
        <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="refused" disabled> Refused
    </label>
    <label for="accomplished">
        <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="accomplished" disabled> Accomplished
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can associate the checkboxes with each other.  Something like this using the `data` attribute would work:

**Updated HTML**

```
<label for="yes">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="yes" id="yes" class="option-yes" data-partner="accomplished">Yes
</label>
<label for="no">
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="no" id="no" class="option-no" data-partner="refused">No
</label>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('input[name="radio1"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="radio2]').prop('checked',false);
  $('#'+$(this).data('partner')).prop('checked',true);
});
```

JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/bw21cxo5/3/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use plain `JS` when checking radio buttons.

Try this:

```
$('input[name="radio1"]').on('change', function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass('option-no')) {
    $('#refused').get(0).checked = true;
  } else {
    $('#accomplished').get(0).checked = true;
  }
});
```

The problem with your code is instead of `attr` you should have used `prop`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) is the difference between them.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bw21cxo5/2/)